# Invalid mount target error while creating volumes using docker-compose.yml on windows 8

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy this image but getting rejected reponse.
How to define volume for windows 8 using yml file ??
I am using docker toolbox for working with docker on windows 8.

```
Docker version 17.04.0-ce, build 4845c56  
docker-compose version 1.12.0, build ee0f34e1
```

env. variable:

```
export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS="true"
```

I am executing the following command from below path in my windows laptop:

```
cds_hyd_16_user@cds_hyd_16 MINGW64 /d/docker-practice  
$docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml myapp
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
redis:  
    image: redis  
    ports:  
    - "6379:6379"  
    volumes:  
    - D:\docker-practice\data:D:\docker-practice\data  
    deploy:  
        placement:  
            constraints: [node.role == manager]  
    networks:  
    - webnet
```

Below is my VirtualBox shared folder structure:

[image]

Comment: I think Docker has too many bugs!